# CursorAdapter can't be instantiated !

Tags: android, database, sqlite, listview, android-cursoradapter

I have a *DataBaseHelper* which has a `fetchData()` method that returns a `Cursor` containing a whole table rows drom an .sqlite file in assest folder.

I wrote this:

```
    try {
        Cursor cursor = myDbHelper.fetchData("tableName");
        txt.setText("Done!"); //for check only

    } catch (Exception e){
        txt.setText("Can't fetch data !");
    }
```

I added these two lines at the end of the *try block*. I did this in order to attach a **CursorAdapter** `ca` to a **ListView** `lv` :

```
        CursorAdapter ca = new CursorAdapter(getBaseContext(), cursor, false);
        lv.setAdapter(ca);
```

However, I got an error message at the *CursorAdapter* instantiation line:

> Cannot instantiate the type CursorAdapter

**What is wrong here ? am I using the wrong adapter to fetch from a database?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm.... let's see:
First we open reference page for [CursorAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html).

Then we look at header, and we can read: 
public **abstract** class CursorAdapter
Abstract classes can't be instantiated in Java (and in any other language implementing that concept) it's feature not a bug.
Few lines more we can find link to [SimpleCursorAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html) which is not abstract.
So simple solution is "just use SimpleCustomAdapter instead of abstract CursorAdapter.

SimpleCursorAdapter exists in Android API since Android 1.0 (API lvl1).

Comment: `SimpleCursorAdapter`'s constructor is API level 11. My project's build target is 1.6 . Thanks

Comment: In my documentation, SimpleCursorAdapter is marked as "Since: API Level 1" - so, yes - you can use it.

Comment: The only constructor in the class is API level 11. Does this change anything?

Comment: No it doesn't you as mentioned above SCA is present from Android's beginning